# Can selenium be used for INTRAnet? not INTERnet

Tags: selenium

Can selenium be used to access intranet websites in the following format? I am trying to access a website that is in the form something/ 
where something is just a word that doesn't contain https or .com etc.

Also, suppose not, then could it still be used to play around with websites whose url is of the form https://something 
where again, something is just a word that doesn't contain https or .com etc.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("something/")
```

Comment: Yes of course. Why not? At least if your intranet page is browsable using a classical internet browser.

Comment: @Kanak It doesn't seem to work though for sites of the form something/. Could you send me an example of it working for you?

Comment: You necessarily have a protocole to access your webpage via webbrowers, be it internally or externally served. Did you try `driver.get("http://something/")`?

Comment: Oh that works!! Thanks! I had tried it with https, but that didn't work. Could you please explain to me the difference between using http and https? Thanks!

Comment: "something/" isn't a valid URL. What do you expect selenium to do with that? Open a file named "something"? "something.html"? Go to "something.com"? "something.net"?

Comment: @bryan When I do that in my normal browser it works though for intranet. That's all I have to type

Comment: @graphtheory123: right, that's your browser internally making assumptions about what you intend. The underlying selenium library -- and the underlying libraries that your browser uses -- don't make those assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

You necessarily have an [application protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) (for example HTTP, HTTPS, BGP, DHCP, DNS, FTP, IMAP, LDAP, MGCP, ...) that specifies the methods used by hosts in a communications network. In your case, to access your page, you may want to try

```
driver.get("http://something/")
```

---

In reaction to your question in comment about the difference between http and https: as [it reads here](https://www.instantssl.com/https-tutorials/what-is-https.html)

> Using HTTPS, the computers agree on a "code" between them, and then they scramble the messages using that "code" so that no one in between can read them. This keeps your information safe from hackers.

---

To directly access your site while dealing with SSL certificates (https), you may want to try

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://something/")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes I asked a new question in the comments of the answer that Bryan just posted. If you could address that that would be great

Comment: @graph I addressed your other comment/question in practice. Verbally, this is because Selenium may not deal with ssl certificates automatically, i.e. loading https directly may not work automatically. The redirection from http to https (that you see) circumvents the problem. Test my update above. Does it work?

Comment: the new thing you posted doesn't work on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Selenium works with any valid URL. "something" isn't a valid URL. A valid URL needs a scheme (http, ftp, etc), so that selenium knows how to access the data. For example, "http://something" is valid, as is "file:///something" (though by "valid" I mean they are syntactically valid). They may not return any results unless there's an intranet server named "something" or a file on your system named "/something".

For more information about what makes up a proper url, one fairly simple description is on the wikipedia entry for [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I am still curious about though is why https:// something didn't work whereas http:// something did, especially because after the website loads, the address bar displays https:// something instead of http:// something